# Where does association extension sit in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an association extension method like the following:

```
class Bundle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items do
    def foo
    end
  end
```

I tried to use delayed job/sidekiq `delay()` method like the following:

```
b.items.delay.foo
```

But I can't. You see, when delay is called, association evaluated immediately to an array of records. That array does not have the association extension methods.

So I tried inspecting `b.items.proxy_association.methods`, and to my surprise, `foo()` is not there either.

Which object does my `foo()` method sit in?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, your assosiation is valid, you want to find where it is?

Comment: Yes, I need to know which object it resides in so I can use delay job's `delay()` method properly.

Comment: can you use `before_save:` on the model (items I think)?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Nope.

Comment: @lulalala i don't recommend running a delayed task on an association output - you are risking a stale and outdated input to your delayed task. i'd use a class method that runs delayed and find the association internally, ensuring data integrity.

Comment: @EladMeidar my `foo` method does not have such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks those who answered. They are not 100% correct but not by far. So I'll leave the bounty so it is shared by you guys.

The `BundleItemsAssociationExtension` is mixed into the ActiveRecord::Relation object. So when I call:

```
bundle.items.scoped.methods # returns array containing my :foo
```

So the ActiveRecord::Relation object is the one containing my extension methods.

---

As a side note: it turns out I can't use Delayed Job on Relation object, because it includes an anonymous module that can't be serialized. So in the end I have to use class method to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: FYI, `b.items.proxy_association.options[:extend]` gives you a Module which contains the definition of your `def foo ... end`. 
BTW, what is `BundleItemsAssociationExtension` exactly? Is it a module or something defined at runtime? Don't know about that.

Comment: @DeanWinchester Yes it should defined at runtime by the `extension_module_name` mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed Job's delay function checks for whether the object responds to the method that is queued and would return a `NoMethodError` because the function is not defined for the Items class. The ways extensions work is by adding a module to the owner class of the proxy_association, in this case you will be able to access the function from `Bundle::BundleItemsAssociationExtension.instance_methods`. Therefore, the delay method won't be able to access foo method even if you pass an association object. I would suggest moving the method to the Items class and then calling delayed job on it.

Comment: First, your NoMethodError theory is probably wrong. It is due to AR relation evaluated to Array of record objects.

Comment: Second, you said extension is included to owner class, which is Bundle. But I don't see that BundleItemsAssociationExtension class in the Bundle ancestor chain. Thoughts? Cheers~

Comment: You are right about the `NoMethodError`. Also since the object that is being passed it Array of records, it would not respond to the `foo` method. Also just saw the snippet from `collection_association.rb` posted below- 
`model.parent.const_set(extension_module_name, Module.new(&block_extension))`
This actually attaches the Module to the parent class of the Bundle, which is why it is not available in the Bundle ancestor chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here in `collection_association.rb`

```
#has_many calls this eventually
def build
  wrap_block_extension
  ...
end
```

And then

```
#here model refers to you model
#block_extension is the block you write with in the has_many definition(def foo blah blah)
def wrap_block_extension
  ...
  model.parent.const_set(extension_module_name, Module.new(&block_extension))
  options[:extend].push("#{model.parent}::#{extension_module_name}".constantize)
end

def extension_module_name
    @extension_module_name ||= "#{model.to_s.demodulize}#{name.to_s.camelize}AssociationExtension"
end
```

I didn't go through the source code, but I think we can get an educated guess from here: `b.items` returns an object(I forgot the class name, some proxy or something, sorry), which when method missing happens, it'll look into somewhere else, including `options[:extend]`, so in this case it gives us what we want by `b.items.foo`.

But when you call `b.items.bar`, it won't find anything relative, so it'll first check if the 'return value' of `b.items`, which is an Array, responds to method `#bar`, and if still not, it calls `Item#bar` for a final try.

In your case, `#delay` is a method recognized by `Array`, so it's really like `tmp1 = b.items.all; tmp2 = tmp1.delay; tmp2.foo`, so `foo` is surely nowhere to be found.